# How to get the params in a custom implementation of a pytorch optimizer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, pytorch

Quick overview of my issue: I'm implementing a custom optimizer, and all I want to do is add two class variables and an extra instruction to the `step()` function. Here's the class code for reference:

```py
class DPSGD(torch.optim.SGD):
    def __init__(
        self, noise_multiplier: float = 0.5, l2_norm_clip: float = 1.5, *args, **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.noise_multiplier = noise_multiplier
        self.l2_norm_clip = l2_norm_clip

    def step(self, closure=None) -> Optional[float]:
        closure = super().step()
        params = []
        
        # works for getting the params I need but there's gotta be a better way
        for group in self.param_groups:
            for p in group["params"]:
                if p.grad is not None:
                    params.append(p)

        # custom function that takes model.parameters()
        privacy.noise_and_clip_parameters(
            params,
            l2_norm_clip=self.l2_norm_clip,
            noise_multiplier=self.noise_multiplier,
        )
        return closure
```

I don't really understand what the `param_groups` are. I know that when the `model.parameters()` are passed to an optimizer like

```py
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

they are taken and converted into the `param_groups` as a class variable, but I don't know a simple way to just get the original params out as they were. Is there a way to extract those original `model.parameters()` that's already implemented in the base optimizer class? My goal is to not have to use that nested for loop because I'm planning on extending other torch optimizers in the same manner and for readability I'd rather avoid writing more code than I need to.

Comment: That nested for-loop's performance is in the noise.

Comment: @erip I'm a little confused of what you mean by that, can you elaborate?

Comment: From your description it's not clear _why_ you want to avoid the nested for loop. If it's because of some perceived performance issue with the looping over parameters, it will not impact anything.

Comment: @erip good point, just edited and added the reason.

Comment: You could use list comprehension: `params = [(p, p.grad) for group in self.param_groups for p in group['params'] if p.grad is not None]`